# Removing commented code in Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2012

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, comments, visual-web-developer

What is the best way to remove all the commented code (be it javascript or HTML) be it single line or multiliner in Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2012??

Comment: What do you mean by Supr ?? be reasonable freind

Comment: Why do you want to delete comments? Are they bugging you?

Answer (score 1):

highlight all code

then press CTRL+K, CTRL+C to comment selection

press CTRL+K, CTRL+U to uncomment selection

[PRE DEFINE HOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)